# Where can I find a list of rejected edit suggestions?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I was just looking at my edit suggestions. Last I checked, I had 51 edits accepted and 2 rejected. Where can I find out what those rejected edits were, so I can learn from the experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edits you've suggested appear in the Activity tab on your profile page, and you can filter  to produce *just* a list of suggested edits [like so](https://askubuntu.com/users/13398/scott-severance?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Unfortunately, I don't know of a good way to find the ones that are *rejected* short of clicking through each one... Here's one of the two: https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/6169

As for learning from experience: you're probably best off just periodically going back to the list and checking for rejections.