# What to do when a user asks a question editing an another question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Today I was looking at the suggested edits and I found [edit #70248](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/70248).

The edit was made to [a question about a graphics problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237333) and consisted in the following text:

> pls do tell me how to connect to the wireless network(tata photon usb model).
>   can someone solve this out pls...

It is fairly obvious that the edit should be rejected, but **how to inform the user about what he/she should do?** Does the rejection reason reach the user? Is it somehow possible to leave a private message for the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rejection reason is shown to the user.

*Invalid edit* is the canned rejection reason that applies to edits that attempt to comment on or reply to the post.

However, if you can point the misguided editor in the right direction by giving a custom rejection reason, then by all means, do that!

You can tell them to post a new question. One of the reviewers of that suggested edit did just that. I've done that several times as well.

Comment: Where does one see the rejection reason? Is it as explained here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2222/25656 ?